# FCM - messaging().onMessage duplicate callbacks - does not unmount with useEffect

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm using FCM to send messages to an Android app which then renders the messages into a FlatList component. When I new FCM message is received I want to refresh the FlatList component so the latest message is displayed in the list. I'm using useEffect to trigger the refresh with setRefreshPage().

The code below works great, except that every time an FCM message is received and the useEffect fires it appears to create a second foreground listener which results in duplicate notifications of subsequent messages. I don't think the unsubscribeOnMessage(); is removing the existing foreground listener in useEffect.

The callbacks double each time, i.e. 1 FCM message callback on the first message receipt, then 2 callbacks for the next message, 4 callbacks for the next, etc. Which makes me think extra messaging().onMessage foreground listeners are being created on each useEffect trigger.

What's the right way of removing the messaging listener when the useEffect is fired?

I've only tested this code on Android so far.

```
function HomeScreen() {

const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [refreshPage, setRefreshPage] = useState(false);

useEffect(async () => {

  const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('storedMessages');

  // ...functions to retrieve and sort historical messages into array "sortedInput"

  setData(sortedInput);  // setState to provide initial data for FlatList component

  };

  const unsubscribeOnMessage = messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {

    console.log("DEBUG: Received FCM message: " + JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));

    // Function to process new message and insert into local storage
    await _handleNewMessage(remoteMessage);

    // Display notification to user
    await onDisplayNotification(remoteMessage);

    // Trigger refresh of FlatList component with setState
    setRefreshPage(Math.random() * 100);

  });

  return () => {
    unsubscribeOnMessage();
  };

}, [refreshPage]);


// Render messages into FlatList view
function renderMessagesFlatList(data) {

  if (isLoading) {

    return (
      <ActivityIndicator
        size="large"
        color="#0000ff"
        />
    );

  } else if (data.length === 0) {

    return (
    <Text>No notifications to display</Text>
    );

    } else {

  return (
  <FlatList
      data={data}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <>
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1 }}>
          <Image
            style={{ width: 40, height: 40 }}
            source={{uri:item.icon}}
          />
            <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingLeft: 5 }}>
            <Text style={{ color: '#000000', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{item.sender}</Text>
            <Text>{timeSince(item.time)}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          <Text style={{ paddingTop: 4 }}>{item.body}</Text>
          <Divider style={{ backgroundColor: '#e7e5e5', height: 2, marginTop: 5, marginBottom: 5 }} />
          </>
        )}
    />
  );

  }
};


  return (
      <View style={{ margin: 5 }} >
      {console.log("DEBUG: isLoading = " + isLoading)}
      {console.log("DEBUG: data = " + JSON.stringify(data))}

      {renderMessagesFlatList(data)}

      </View>
  );

};
```

Here is what I end up seeing in the logfiles when I send one FCM message per minute:

```
04-22 08:40:00.000 ReactNativeJS: DEBUG: Received FCM message: {...}

04-22 08:41:00.000 ReactNativeJS: DEBUG: Received FCM message: {...}
04-22 08:41:00.006 ReactNativeJS: DEBUG: Received FCM message: {...}

04-22 08:42:00.000 ReactNativeJS: DEBUG: Received FCM message: {...}
04-22 08:42:00.004 ReactNativeJS: DEBUG: Received FCM message: {...}
04-22 08:42:00.009 ReactNativeJS: DEBUG: Received FCM message: {...}
04-22 08:42:00.014 ReactNativeJS: DEBUG: Received FCM message: {...}

04-22 08:43:00.000 ReactNativeJS: DEBUG: Received FCM message: {...}
04-22 08:43:00.006 ReactNativeJS: DEBUG: Received FCM message: {...}
04-22 08:43:00.011 ReactNativeJS: DEBUG: Received FCM message: {...}
04-22 08:43:00.017 ReactNativeJS: DEBUG: Received FCM message: {...}
04-22 08:43:00.021 ReactNativeJS: DEBUG: Received FCM message: {...}
04-22 08:43:00.028 ReactNativeJS: DEBUG: Received FCM message: {...}
04-22 08:43:00.036 ReactNativeJS: DEBUG: Received FCM message: {...}
04-22 08:43:00.049 ReactNativeJS: DEBUG: Received FCM message: {...}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting FCM being repeatedly updated because of this 2 lines, causing a loop which is a anti-pattern.

```
setRefreshPage(Math.random() * 100);  //<-- You are updating the state refreshPage


}, [refreshPage]); // <--- You use refreshPage as a dependency means useEffect will be called. And then you will setRefreshPage again
```

I cannot advise you further than this because I'm not sure why you did setRefreshPage. If you want it to only fire once when page load then you remove the refreshPage dependency.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! When an FCM message is received while the app is in the foreground, I'm using the state refreshPage to trigger a refresh of HomeScreen() to update the FlatList component to include the latest message. I've expanded the original question with some more code which shows the wider context. If I remove the refreshPage dependency then the FlatList renders fine on the initial load, but isn't upgraded when a new message is received. Thanks.

Comment: You do not need to trigger refresh as it is a `listener`, it will trigger on every `messaging().onMessage`, you just need to `setData` in your listener to update the data and use extraData={data} in your flatlist component to trigger a component refresh whenever there's new data.. https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#extradata